# How to create database in new user instead of root?

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I created user `wanghao` in MySQL and I want to create database in `wanghao` but an "access denied" error occurred. I want to create a database in user `wanghao` directly instead of using the following method.

```
create database exdb

grant all privileges on exdb.* to wanghao@localhost identified  by 'wanghao'
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this like

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON exdb.* To 'wanghao'@'hostname' IDENTIFIED BY 'password';
```

You must have the single quotes in there. 'localhost' tells MySQL you only want it from the same machine.